# JavaScript variable not correctly interpreted

Tags: javascript, ajax

In the header section of a HTML page, I have the following JavaScript-/Ajax-Function:

```
function getDataFromBackend(cmp){

$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'getRun.php?run='+cmp,
    dataType: 'script',
    success: loadData
});}
```

`getRun` returns an array like [[2, 4, 5, 57]]

`loadData` is defined as follows:

```
                function loadData(dataFromAjax){

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        console.log(dataFromAjax);
                        chartRunnerDist.load({
                            columns: dataFromAjax
                        });     
                    }, 100);
            }
```

In the console, I see the correct values. If I copy the console content behind `columns:` part manually, everything is fine. But `dataFromAjax` doesn't seem to be interpreted correctly. Do I have to explicitly convert it to an array?

Comment: What is `chartRunnerDist()`? What do you mean exactly by "interpreted correctly"?

Comment: That depends, generally ajax only returns strings, not arrays, but jQuery does does do some magic based on things like `dataType` to convert certain structures. Why is your `dataType` set to `script`, what exactly is the PHP returning?

Comment: Why not just try `console.log(typeof dataFromAjax);` and see what you've got

Comment: can you add a snapshot of your console.log ?

Comment: typeof returns string, still JSON.parse does not help.

Comment: My php returns: 
[[1, 0, 6, 7, 9, 18, 29, 29, 25, 78, 65, 99, 109, 141, 154, 189, 192, 259, 208, 218, 239, 229, 250, 237, 199, 160, 127, 143, 106, 95, 90, 79, 52, 62, 49, 46, 39, 37, 17, 21, 22, 14, 15, 8, 9, 8, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to parse the response to convert it from a string to an object. Use `JSON.parse(dataFromAjax)`

Comment: That solved my issue. (At first, I still received an error message, but that was for another reason.) Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function loadData(dataFromAjax){
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(dataFromAjax);
            chartRunnerDist.load({
                columns: dataFromAjax[0]
            });     
        }, 100);
}
```